# How to create a method in a class that will determine the intersection of circles?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, methods

I have a code

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def dist(self, other_point):  # the dist method takes another object of class Point and finds the Euclidean distance between two points.
        d = (other_point.x - self.x) ** 2 + (other_point.y - self.y) ** 2
        return d**(1/2)
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, center,radius):  # a constructor that takes an object of class Point, the center point of the circle, and a number, the radius of the circle;
        self.center = center  # center and radius return the center and radius of the circle, respectively;
        self.radius = radius
    def square(self):
        S = 3.14 * self.radius**2
        return S  # returns the area of a circle
```

I need to add a `do_intersect` method to `class Circle`, which will accept another object of the Circle class and return True or False depending on whether the circles intersect or not.

I added this:

```
    def do_intersect(self, circle_2):
        if (((self.center[0] - circle_2.center[0]) + (self.center[1] - circle_2.center[1])) ** 2) ** 0.5 <= self.radius + circle_2.radius:
            return True
        return False
```

But I have an error `'Point' object does not support indexing` when the test program enters `Circle(Point(0, 0), 10).do_intersect(Circle(Point(0, 0), 10))`

Please, help me to fix this problem

Comment: You want `self.center.x` and `self.center.y` rather than `self.center[0]` and `self.center[1]`

Comment: By the way, you can make your code a bit faster.  Rather than checking if `sqrt(...) < r1 + r2`, instead check if `... < (r1 + r2)**2`.  Squaring is a lot faster than square rooting.  You can also just write `return ... < ...` rather than needing an `if` statement.

Comment: Yes, it helped, thank you!

Comment: `do_intersect` isn’t a very strong name, I thing that will do an intersection, not work out if the two circles intersect - why not use something that hints more at the result, e.g. `is_intersecting` Must have a true/false result mustn’t it?